# How to use a folder besides the Desktop folder as the default for opening and saving files in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, firefox, desktop, files-folders

Many desktop applications (such as Mozilla's Firefox web browser) use the `Desktop` folder as the default to open/save files.  For example, in Firefox, if you go to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/) and click on the `Choose file` button, it will always open up a dialog box pointing to the `Desktop` folder.

I prefer to keep the Windows Desktop fairly empty, and so I use a different folder as my "active" folder.  To keep it simple for this question, let's just call it `C:\Stuff`.

What I would like is when an open/save dialog box is opened (like the one mentioned above), for the dialog box to point to the `C:\Stuff` folder.  Given that I don't want to have to recompile every application with this change (and not all application are open-source), I would like to know how to accomplish this in Windows 7.

Importantly, please note that I want all the files to be stored in `C:\Stuff` and not the `Desktop` folder.  I also do use the `Desktop` folder for a few things, so I don't want to clutter up the `Desktop` folder, or have hundreds of icons on the desktop (I'm happy with the 8 icons I currently have).

Comment: Does this [Change default download location in Windows 7](https://www.howtoguides.org/change-default-download-location-in-windows-7) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill I appreciate the link, but that won't work.  That technique just changes the `Download` folder for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Probably IE is the only program that uses that location. Everything else (like other browers) does it's own thing. I think you would need to write a hook into the DLL that manages the system open/save dialog. That requires serious programming skills. Note that some programs already do this (like the other browsers)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks.  What about symbolic links, hard links, junctions, etc.?  I know a bunch of people here (possibly yourself included) use them regularly for different uses.  I use them just once in a while, so I defer to the experience and knowledge of others.

Comment: Links would just move the Desktop somewhere else. They won't solve your issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ya, that's what I was thinking too.

Answer (score 0):

The default open/save folder is a per program setting. The open/save dialog can also 'remember' the last chosen folder and will return there.

Taking your example of virustotal.com, it presented my Downloads folder. I then browsed to My Documents and opened a file from there, uploading it. I closed my browser, opened it again and returned to virustotal. Clicked the upload button and the dialog opened in the My Documents folder.

If you want to change the location of a default folder like Downloads or My Documents, you can open explorer and under `This PC` right click on `Downloads` and click `Properties`. Navigate to `Location` and chose a new location for your standard download folder. You can do the same for My Documents, Music, ...

Comment: Thanks.  Which web browser did you try?

Comment: I tried this with Chrome, Edge (i know) and Firefox. All three browser showed the same behaviour, its the default windows behaviour of the File Dialog.

Comment: Hmmm... I get a different behaviour in Firefox.  Which version of Firefox did you test, and which version of Windows?  In Firefox, the `Open` dialog box always comes up pointing to the `Desktop` folder for me on sites like VirusTotal.  Maybe you somehow fixed it, which would be fantastic, but we need to figure out what you did!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm on a different machine atm, so i have retested with Firefox, version 89.0.1, and had the same results. I opened firefox, went to virustotal, picked a file and in the file dialog browsed to c:\windows\system32 and chose cmd.exe as file to upload.  After receiving the results, i browsed to cnn.com and closed firefox. I opened firefox again, went to virustotal and clicked Choose file again. The file dialog opened on c:\windows\system32 where i last left it.

Comment: For more information on the windows file dialog, check out https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog?view=net-5.0 Specifically the InitialDirectory and RestoreDirectory methods. But again, this is handled on a per app basis and default behaviour is to restore the file dialog to the last used folder if it still exists.

Comment: Did some more testing. Opening the file dialog on other websites resulted in firefox always first defaulting to desktop. Once ive made use of it once, it will remember the last directory. So it seems Firefox treats it as a different dialog per website.